# Visual Studio C++ exception... weirdness

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, exception, boost

I have a Qt application that I compile in **release** configuration, run, and then perform operation X in the program. Everything runs fine.

I then compile it in **debug** configuration, run *without debugging* (so CTRL+F5), perform operation X in the program. Everything *still* runs dandy fine.

But when I try to run the debug configuration *with debugging* (so just F5) and then perform operation X, Visual Studio breaks in with a message that an exception has been thrown... in a *completely unrelated* part of the program (code being executed is far from the site where VS breaks, in the QHash template)... and then VS hangs and I have to kill it with the Task Manager. I can repeat this ad infinitum, and it always freaks out the same way.

Boost::exception is used for the exceptions. VS is 2008, SP1. Qt is 4.6.2, using the precompiled VS binaries from the Qt site.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have first-chance exception handling enabled, would you?  (Debug -> Exceptions; see if any check boxes are checked).

Comment: Um... yes. "C++ Exceptions" is checked. Removing the checks fixes the problem. But I don't remember ever setting these to checked. Anyway, your solution works and now I feel like a moron. If you make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: But still.. there are no exceptions being thrown in the executing code (no code that _could_ throw either).

Comment: "no code that could throw either" Are you sure of that?

Comment: Might that exception be thrown in a different thread?

Comment: Nate got it. It's a different thread throwing it. I excluded thread weirdness because the bug was very repeatable... I guess you never know with threads.

Comment: I've never had it break in a different thread than the one from which the exception was thrown.  Good thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio has a feature called "first chance exception handling" where, when running attached to the debugger, you can have the debugger break when exceptions of certain types are thrown.

You can change these settings by going to `Debug -> Exceptions` (Ctrl+Alt+E) and (un)checking the appropriate checkboxes.

When it breaks you should get a message in the Output window indicating what exception was thrown.

If you have `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` enabled (it is enabled by default in debug builds), it can cause a lot of iterator errors to throw exceptions instead of performing operations that would cause access violations.  That's the only thing I can think of off the top of my head that would cause an exception to occur "randomly."